# Async/Await order

Tags: javascript, async-await, request, xml-parsing, cheerio

I'm working on a small parser that look at both a rss.xml file and extract information from the link that I find inside the xml items.

I'm able to get all the information I am looking for, now my only problem is I don't really understand how Async/Await works.

```
const Parser = require('rss-parser');
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const request = require('request');

const parser = new Parser(
    { 
        customFields: {
            item: [
                ['media:thumbnail', 'preview']
            ]
        }
    }
);
const URL = 'https://www.dimensions.guide/element/rss.xml';
const updatedItems = [];
var updatedItem = {};

(async () => {
    const feed = await parser.parseURL(URL);

    await feed.items.forEach(item => {
        request(item.link, (err, res, html) => {
            if(!err && res.statusCode == 200){
                const $ = cheerio.load(html);

                updatedItem = {
                    "title": $('h1.title-text-hover-tag').text(),
                    "category": $('.header-wrapper-lower-links > a.parent-link').first().text(),
                    "subCategory": $('.header-wrapper-lower-links > a.parent-link').last().text(),
                    "link": item.link,
                    "preview": item.preview.$.url,
                    "lastUpdate": item.pubDate,
                }
                updatedItems.push(updatedItem)
            }
        });
    });
    console.log(updatedItems)
})();
```

This is my code.

1. First, I'm getting the information from my xml file.
2. I'm parsing each item from the rss feed, getting the link to scrape the information I need.
3. When I have all the information I need, I'm pushing the item to my array.
4. Only when I'm done checking *EVERY* link, I want to log the updatedItems I found.

Right now, it's showing an empty array before doing anything else.
Any Idea?

I'm open to any improvement to my code, I'm really starting to code as a hobby and don't know much

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to `await` the return value of `feed.items.forEach(..)` which is `undefined`. To fix that, you can use `.map(..)` instead of `.forEach(..)` and create an array of promises which you can wait for, here is an example:

```
await Promise.all(await feed.items.map(item => {
  return request(item.link, (err, res, html) => {
    ..
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe your code should look like below. Hope it work!

```
const Parser = require('rss-parser');
    const cheerio = require('cheerio')
    const request = require('request');

    const parser = new Parser(
        { 
            customFields: {
                item: [
                    ['media:thumbnail', 'preview']
                ]
            }
        }
    );
    const URL = 'https://www.dimensions.guide/element/rss.xml';
    const updatedItems = [];
    var updatedItem = {};

    function doRequest(url) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function (error, res, body) {
          if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
            resolve([error, res, body]);
          } else {
            reject(error);
          }
        });
      });
    }

    (async () => {
        const feed = await parser.parseURL(URL);

        feed.items.forEach(async (item) => {
           const [err, res, html] = await doRequest(item.link);

           if(!err && res.statusCode == 200){
                const $ = cheerio.load(html);

                updatedItem = {
                    "title": $('h1.title-text-hover-tag').text(),
                    "category": $('.header-wrapper-lower-links > a.parent-link').first().text(),
                    "subCategory": $('.header-wrapper-lower-links > a.parent-link').last().text(),
                    "link": item.link,
                    "preview": item.preview.$.url,
                    "lastUpdate": item.pubDate,
                }
                updatedItems.push(updatedItem)
            }
        });
        console.log(updatedItems)
    })();
```